# Show Alert if Calendar Access is Denied Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, swift3, alert

I am trying to have a "Go to settings" alert pop if the user denies access to the calendar. It works once the user has denied the calendar and reopens the app. But I need the alert to pop up right after the user denies access.

Here is my calendar access code:

```
/**
 */
func requestDeniedAlert() -> UIAlertController {
let requestAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Calendar Access Denied", message: "Please Allow Calendar Access In Settings", preferredStyle: .alert)
let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Go To Settings", style: .default){(action) in
    print("The User Will Be Taken To the Settings")
    let goToSettings = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
    UIApplication.shared.open(goToSettings!)
}
requestAlertController.addAction(settingsAction)

return requestAlertController
}

/**
 reuestCalendarPermissions:
 @param
 @return
 */
func requestCalendarPermissions() {
eventInstance.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: {(accessGranted: Bool, error: Error?) in

    if accessGranted == true {
        print("Access Has Been Granted")
        MainScreenTableView.flagVariable.statusFlag = true
    }
    else {
        print("Change Settings to Allow Access")
        MainScreenTableView.flagVariable.statusFlag = false
    }
})
}

/**
 checkStatus:
 Notes: This function checks if the User has given calendar access to app
 If access is restricted or denied, a "Go To Settings" view will appear
 */
func checkStatus() {
let currentStatus = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event)

if currentStatus == EKAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined {
    requestCalendarPermissions()
}
else if currentStatus == EKAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
    print("Access Has Been Granted")
    MainScreenTableView.flagVariable.statusFlag = true
}
else if (currentStatus == EKAuthorizationStatus.denied) || (currentStatus == EKAuthorizationStatus.restricted){
    print("Access Has Been Denied")
    MainScreenTableView.flagVariable.statusFlag = false
}
}
```

I am working with a UITableViewController which is seemingly what is making this such a pain. The way I have it now I am setting a flag and then in the tableview I am presenting the alert. But I cannot get the alert to pop up immediately after the user denies access.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why would you show an alert right after the user denies access? The user already knows that access is denied since they just denied it.

Comment: Well the app won't be usable unless it has access to the calendars. So if they deny access then I want to have a pop up that only allows them to go to settings and grant access to the calendars. Kinda like some apps won't let you do anything unless you give them access to location services.

Comment: Well, your app may get rejected if app won't work when access is denied. I believe I read somewhere that app is supposed to work even if some of it's features can't be enabled due to user's settings.

Comment: I guess that I could have the alert come up if the user tries use anything in the app. It solely relies on the calendar working for anything to get done.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to present your alert from inside the completion handler of the call to `eventInstance.requestAccess` when `accessGranted == false`.

`accessGranted` will be `false` the one time access is requested and the user taps on Deny or any time after that when the user runs the app and access is still denied.

Comment: When put the present directly into the accessGranted == false, I get the    `error attempt to present whose view is not in the window hierarchy`

Comment: You have to present the alert from a view controller that is already visible.

Comment: Once I do that though it doesn't come up when the user denies the calendar. Maybe if I check the status in view did appear?